# Hint to evaluate $\int x^8\sqrt{1 - x^6} dx $

Tags: calculus

I want to evaluate

$$\int x^8\sqrt{1 - x^6} dx $$

I tried substitution by picking $u = 1- x^6$ but that didn't work out well. Any hint or help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would try $x^3=\sin t$

Comment: $x^8=\frac{1}{9}d(x^9), x^6=(x^9)^{\frac{2}{3}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $x^3=\sin t$. Then $3x^2dx=\cos t dt$, so
$$\int x^8\sqrt{1-x^6}dx=\frac{1}{3}\int(x^3)^2\sqrt{1-(x^3)^2}(3x^2dx) = \frac{1}{3} \int\sin^2(t)\sqrt{1-\sin^2(t)}\cos tdt =\\ =\frac{1}{3}\int(\sin t\,\cos t)^2 dt =\frac{1}{12}\int \sin^2(2t)dt=$$
and probably you can finish.

Answer (score 1):

If you pick $u = x^3$ then $du = 3x^2 dx$ and you have that 
$$ \int x^8 \sqrt{1 - x^6} dx = \frac{1}{3} \int u^2\sqrt{1 - u^2} du  $$
From here, you can use trig substitution by $ u = \sin(\theta)$ then $du = \cos(\theta) d\theta$ and your integral becomes
$$ \frac{1}{3}\int \sin^2(\theta) \cos^2(\theta) d\theta $$

Can you take it from here?